# Code inside while loop not being executed JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify-app

I am working with this while loop and it is not working. I decided to use the Google Chrome debugger and I saw that the code inside is not being executed.

All the time it checks the condition, starts the first line of the code inside, and goes back again to check the condition.

It is a NodeJS server and I am using the Spotify API.

```
app.get('/process', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  let init_array = text.split(" ");
  let modtext = init_array;

  while (init_array.length != 0) {
    spotifyApi.searchTracks(modtext.join(" "))
      .then(function (data) {
        try {
          console.log(data.body.tracks.items[0].name);
          for (let i = 0; i < modtext.length; i++) {
            init_array.shift();
          }
          modtext = init_array;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("No song");
          modtext.pop();
        }
      });
  }


  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: in `let init_array = text.split(" ");`, where is the definition of `text`?

Comment: At the beginning of the code. Out of everything.

Comment: sidenote, by doing `modtext.join(" ")` you're just going to repeat the same call n* how many items in that array.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. But that is not the problem, I changed that part for "Love" (which is the title of one song) and the same happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is best understood by understanding how node.js uses an event loop.  At its core, node.js runs your Javascript in a single thread and it uses an event loop in order to manage the completion of things outside that single thread such as timers, network operations, file operations, etc...

Let's first start with a very simple `while()` loop:

```
let done = false;

setTimeout(() => {
    done = true;
}, 100);

while(!done) {
     // do whatever you want here
}
console.log("done with while loop");    // never gets called
```

At first blush, you would think that the `while` loop would run for 100ms and then `done` would be set to true and the `while` loop would exit.  That is not what happens.  In fact, this is an infinite while loop.  It runs and runs and runs and the variable `done` is never set to `true`.  The `console.log()` at the end never runs.

It has this issue because `setTimeout()` is an asynchronous operation and it communicates its completion through the event loop.  But, as we described above, node.js runs its Javascript as single threaded and only gets the next event from the event loop when that single thread finishes what it's doing.  But, the `while` can't finish what it's doing until `done` gets set to `true`, but `done` can't get set to true until the `while` loop finishes.  It's a stand-off and the while loop just runs forever.

So, in a nutshell, while any sort of loop is running, NO asynchronous operation ever gets its result processed (unless it's using `await` inside the loop which is something different).  Asynchronous operations (or anything that uses the event loop) has to wait until the current running Javascript is done and then the interpreter can go back to the event loop.

---

Your while loop has the exact same issue.   `spotifyApi.searchTracks()` is an asynchronous operation that returns a promise and all promises communicate their results via the event queue.  So, you have the same standoff.  Your `.then()` handler can't get called until the `while` loop finishes, but your `while` loop can't finish until the `.then()` handler gets called.  Your `while` loop will just loop infinitely until you exhaust some system resource and your `.then()` handlers never get a chance to execute.

---

Since you haven't included code in your request handler that actually produces some result or action (all it appears to do is just modify some local variables), it's not obvious what exactly you're trying to accomplish and thus how to better write this code.

You appear to have N searches to do and you're logging something in each search.  You could do them all in parallel and just use `Promise.all()` to track when they are all done (no `while` loop at all).  Or, you can sequence them so you run one, get its result, then run another.  Your question doesn't give us enough info to know what the best option would be.

Here's one possible solution:

**Sequence the operations using async/await**

Here the request handler is declared `async` so we can use `await` inside the `while` loop.  That will suspend the `while` loop and allow other events to process while waiting for the promise to resolve.

```
app.get('/process', ensureAuthenticated, async function (req, res) {
  let init_array = text.split(" ");
  let modtext = init_array;

  while (init_array.length != 0) {
    try {
      let data = await spotifyApi.searchTracks(modtext.join(" "));
      console.log(data.body.tracks.items[0].name);
      for (let i = 0; i < modtext.length; i++) {
        init_array.shift();
      }
      modtext = init_array;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("No song");
      modtext.pop();
    }
  }
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: Exactly, this was the problem. Thank you so much for your explanation. I can understand why it was not working before.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're only seeing one line execute is because it's asynchronous. When you call an asynchronous function, it returns immediately and continues to do its work in the background. Once it's done, it calls another function (a "callback") and passes the results of the function to that. That's why your code has to go inside of a call to `then()` rather than just being on the next line of code.

In this case, `spotifyApi.searchTracks()` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). Once the Spotify API has *completed* the search, the function in `then()` will run.

Comment: But actually, my code is inside ```then()``` no?. Debugging it I noticed that the content of ```modtext.join(" ")``` in the line ```spotifyApi.searchTracks(modtext.join(" ")``` is not changing during the execution. But it should change if I am not wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Lets use async/await to solve this problem, I have no clue what data you get in a `text` but I think it is good example to understand a concept of asynchronous processing.

```
app.get('/process', ensureAuthenticated, async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const modtext = text.split(" ");
    const promises = modtext.map(item => spotify.searchTracks(item));
    const response = await Promise.all(promises);

    response.forEach(data => {
       // if you use lodash, simply use a get function `get(data, 'body.tracks.items[0].name')` => no need to check existence of inner attributes
       // or use something like this
       if (data && data.body && data.body.track && data.body.tracks.items && data.body.tracks.items[0]) {
          console.log(data.body.tracks.items[0].name);
       } else { 
          console.log('No song');
       }
    });

    res.redirect('/');
  } catch(err) {
     next(err)
  }
});
```

For me much simpler and cleaner code, again, i dont know what is structure of your `text` attribute and logic behind it, so maybe you will have to make some changes.